# pyspark union over combination of RDDs

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, distinct, union, rdd

I have multiple RDDs, each consists of list of users. How can I get distinct union of each combination of these RDDs in a distributed way?

**EDIT**

Ok as I mentioned, it's not about getting the dictinct union of all RDDs and turning them into one RDD, it's about getting the distinct union of **combinations** of RDDs.

Let's say we've got three RDDs of same type, *RDD1, RDD2* and *RDD3*, I want to get size of distinct union of each combination of them as follow:

```
sc.union(RDD1).distinct.count()
sc.union(RDD2).distinct.count()
sc.union(RDD3).distinct.count()
sc.union([RDD1,RDD2]).distinct().count()
sc.union([RDD1,RDD3]).distinct().count()
sc.union([RDD2,RDD3]).distinct().count()
sc.union([RDD1,RDD2,RDD3]).distinct().count()
```

since there's no *RDD of RDDS* in spark, I can't make an RDD of all combinations and map each combination of RDDs to get the result.

also as the number of RDDs increase, the number of combinations increase with `2^n`. How can I achieve this goal?

Best Regards.

Comment: Do you want to union all the RDDs and get one RDD with distinct users?

Comment: sorry for the late response, please read the EDIT part. it's about combination of these RDDs.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty simple if the RDDs are of the same type; just do:

```
rdd = sc.union([rdd1, rdd2, rdd3]).distinct()
```

Comment: sorry for the late response, please read the EDIT part. it's about combination of these RDDs.  not getting the distinct users of union of *All RDDs*.

Comment: Okay what you cant do is RDD($i).map(x->(x,($i)))
and then do the union operation, and with the extra information you can do everything you wanted (using filter) without doing extra unions.

Comment: would you please explain it a bit more? what I understand from what you said is that I can't get this done by mapping the RDD of combinations. though should I go for threads if there's no solution for this?